# Axios обёртка в const и вызов?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет.
допустим это файл А:
но как мне в файл Б поместить resualt.data.url? или обернуть её в переменную и вызывать с другого файла?

```
 async function crystal() {


axios.get('https://api.crystalpay.ru/v1/?', {
    params: {
        s: '',
        n: '',
        o: 'invoice-create',
            amount: '',
            lifetime: '1440',
            redirect: ''
        }}).then(function (result) {
            console.log(resualt.data.url)
        })
            console.log(url);
        }
module.exports = crystal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// в файле A
async function crystal() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.crystalpay.ru/v1/?', {
        params: {
            s: '',
            n: '',
            o: 'invoice-create',
            amount: '',
            lifetime: '1440',
            redirect: ''
        }
    })
    return response.data.url
}

// в файле B
const url = await crystal()
console.log(url)
```